# MySQL “Connector/J 5.1.48” platform-independent on MacOS Mojave issues

Tags: mysql, macos, android-studio

How do I download MySQL “Connector/J 5.1.48” platform-independent on macOS Mojave? There is a project I’m working on and I need this specific connector to work on my computer because there’s a specific Android Studio related project I need it for. When I try downloading it, I get an error message. Just in case it’s not possible, are there any other database replacement options that work well with Android Studio that are simple to implement on macOS?

Link to Connector/J 5.1.48: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAR files already are platform independent... They are not executable

I'm not sure how your error is specific to Android Studio, but mobile apps should not be directly querying a Mysql database, but rather reaching a web API that exposes database results over HTTP

And even if you did want to use mysql drivers in an Android app, you'd add those with Gradle, not JARs

That being said, MacOS isn't the issue either, and there's plenty of database replacements for Mysql